# code for change to UTF-8

Tags: c#, csv

I have a C# code for data table to csv convert.my code is

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",", item.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
        }
        sb = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.Append("\n");

    }

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=mycsvfile.csv";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/csv";

    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

anyone know  how can change the csv to utf-8 ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Comment: What encoding is it to start with?  Some will be UTF-8 compatible already...

Comment: Just set the response encoding type to UTF8.

Comment: @leppie where can I set that???

Comment: @Arun: `HttpResponse.ContentEncoding` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are really up to, but there is a class called `System.Text.Encoding` which has a `static property` called `UTF8`. Using this, you can encode your strings to `UTF-8`

```
System.Text.Encoder utf8enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder();
```

The encoder offers methods to encode text. The same goes with `System.Text.Decoder`-class.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) for reference.